# Android: How to create a View consisting of an EditText?

Tags: android

I'm creating an edit text :

```
EditText et=new EditText(this);
et.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and a View :

```
View myView = new View(this);
```

I want to have (only) the EditText in this view.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times

Comment: Elaborate further on the question.

Comment: @Hades - not the same question.
Now I can create the EditText *but* I want to create a view with that EditText

Comment: EditText is already a view, why would you want to put it inside another view?

Comment: @Belgi, A View cannot contain another view. Only `ViewGroups` can contain other views. Use a `xxxLayout` for whatever is it you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way of putting `Views` (or "UI-Elements") on an Android Activity is to create them (in code or in XML) and put them in a [Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) which is then displayed.

Since you only want one `View`, you can use a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item.

Sample code and further information can be found in the linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you need to show up just the EditText in your activity.For that,you can do:

```
 LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(context);
 EditText et=new EditText(this);
 et.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

 l.addView(et);

 setContentView(l);
```